# Separate element by column on csv java

Tags: java, maven, csv

I have this problem with my csv, I have an array with String values and I want to put it in a csv file, but I also want that every element is in a differente column.
I have try this code(without using external framework) and It does not work, the element are in the same colum:
the output is:

first0first1first2

second0second1second2

third0third1third2

```
    BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:/Users/example.csv"));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i=0; i < id.length; i++) {
        sb.append(id[i] + "\t");    
        sb.append(wec[i] + "\t");
        sb.append("\n");    

    }

    br.write(sb.toString());
    br.close();
}
```

I have also try the example from here:
[example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34590971/java-append-new-column-to-csv-file), but nothing is work...here the output is:
third0,
third1
thir2,

The output that I want, is this:

Colum1 Colum2 Colum3

first0 first1    first2

second0    second1   second2

third0 third1 third2

I am using Java 7 and Maven, so It is not a problem tu use external libreries.

I want that all my element are separeted by column, not "," or other symbol.
Here the expected output:
[expected output](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZW-4oSt8BgcRc_j39eNMghIbci_FVgP-_ZgIi2aO2zU/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: **Where** did you get the wrong output without tabs? Do you want an output separated by blanks? Then replace `\t` with `<blank>`. Or do you want **C**omma **S**eparated **V**alues as output? Then replace `\t` with `,` or `;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try apache commons-csv:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-csv -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then the csv printing becomes very simple:

```
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/example.csv"));    List<String> record = new ArrayList<>();
// ...
for (int i=0; i < id.length; i++) {
    record.add(id[i] + "\t");    
    record.add(wec[i] + "\t");    
}
try (CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(builder, CSVFormat.EXCEL)) {
        csvPrinter.printRecord(record);
}
```

This will deal with all the quirks of csv, like having a comma inside of a field.

Alternatively you can add the comma manually:

```
for (int i=0; i < id.length; i++) {
    sb.append(id[i] + "\t,");  // comma after tab
    sb.append(wec[i] + "\t,"); // comma after tab
    sb.append("\n");    

}
```

**UPDATE**

Excel lets you to select the delimiters, see the picture below
[image]

Comment: new CSVPrinter(builder--> builder is my StringBuilder sb? It doesn not work........ I want that all my element in a different  column, like excel, 1 element = First Row, First column, 2 element = First Row, Second column....

the output with your code is that my element are all in 1 column and 1 row

Comment: What tool to you use to look at this? Usually you can configure the delimiter characters.
I already have some `CSVPrinter` in production and it works perfectly. Can you specify more exactly what kind of output you expect? Unfortunately, csv has lots of variants, see the [rfc](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180).

Comment: I use excel to open the csv file. 
As i sad, I want each element in a different colum! 
Example, my element are : a,b,c,d,e.  The expected output is : a in row1 colum1, b in row1 colum2, c in row1 colum3 , d in row1 colum 4, e in row1 colum5. 
like this :
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZW-4oSt8BgcRc_j39eNMghIbci_FVgP-_ZgIi2aO2zU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Excel gives you lots of options, see the picture I just attached to this answer. You have to specify what kind of **textual output** you need. I.e. if you open it with notepad, then you want to see this and that. Then you have to select the right csv delimiter with excel, and that's it.

Comment: Thank you, there is no way to have directly the output that I have share to us, without use this kind of view in excel?

Comment: Excel uses some characters to create columns based on csv. There is a default setting, and that might differ for each version. So, long story short, you have two options: 1. figure out what that character is (it's not tab, neither a comma, this we learned already) 2. configure Excel-s csv handling somehow.

Comment: it is what I'am looking for... =( thanks anyway for your help

Answer (score 1):

with this code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    sb.append("test0\t");
    sb.append("test1\t");
    sb.append("test2\n");
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

i get the output

```
test0   test1   test2
test0   test1   test2
test0   test1   test2
test0   test1   test2
test0   test1   test2
```

as your code seems to be right, we would need more information. to gain a proper csv format, replace every `\t` with a `,`

Comment: With your code, on my csv file the output is this: first row : "test0test1test2"
 second row:"test0test1test2"   etc. etc....

Comment: @LizLamperouge Again: **where** do you get this output? In which editor or program do you open the csv-file?

Comment: On my csv file that it is automatically open with excel

Comment: If I try to open it with notepad the output is this :"a ","2 ","b ","4 ","c ","5 ","d ","6 ","e ","7 "

Comment: if your csv get opened with excel, it might be that you need to seperate with a comma so excel does recognize it correctly

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15736269)

Comment: @jwenting i know, but how do you want to format the output correctly in a comment? if SO gives this possibility, there is no need for such "answers"