# How to add a new column to a csv file using Apache Commons?

Tags: java, csv, apache-commons

I have a csv file that look like this:

```
name,age,total
xyz,22
abc,20
```

After processing the csv file should look like this:

```
name,age,total
xyz,22,100
abc,20,102
```

After running this code:

```
public class Converter {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(Constants.SAMPLE_CSV_FILE));
        CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(writer, CSVFormat.DEFAULT);
        
        csvPrinter.print(100);
        csvPrinter.print(102);
        
        csvPrinter.close();
    }

}
```

the output csv file becomes like this:

```
100
102
```

I want 100 and 102 to come under the total column. How can I do this?

Comment: You never actually ***read*** the existing data in.  You have to read the data and add the field to every line and then write the updated line.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't override your existing file. Hence, use the appending argument on the FileWriter constructor:

```
FileWriter pw = new FileWriter("C:\\exampleFile.csv",true);
```

Second, as you can see in your result, the CSVPrinter goes through your file by rows. If you want to add a new column, you actually need to iterate over each row and insert the new column's row data on every iteration, as explained thoroughly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34591134/3103891)